# sending an email in outlook based an email that has been selected

Tags: php, sql, function, outlook, href

I am trying to use outlook desktop pop up to send an email when the link is clicked, i have this working but instead of sending it to a manually entered email in the code i want to send it to an email that is selected.
At the moment when a user clicks a button it sends an id but i want it to send the email aswell.

The code below displays a table of data , when the user clicks reject it sends the id and updates in the table , i want it to send the email along with the id if that is possible

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sureToReject(id,email){
  if(confirm("Are you sure you want to reject this booking?")){
   window.location.href ='Breject.php?id='+id+''+'email='+email;
  }
 }    
    </script>


<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['customer_ID'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['Name'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['Email'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['booking_date'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row['booking_time'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['attendee_no'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['booking_reason'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['comments'] ?></td>
            <!-- calls the javascript function above to change 'status' column in booking table -->
          <!--  <td><a href="javascript:sureToApprove(<?php echo $row['customer_ID'];?>)" class="ico del" >Approve</a><br> &nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:sureToReject(<?php echo $row['customer_ID'];?>)" class="ico edit">Delete</a></td> -->
    <td class="text-center">
            <a class='btn btn-info btn-xs' href="javascript:sureToApprove(<?php echo $row['customer_ID'];?>)" >
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Yes</a> 
                <a href="javascript:sureToReject(<?php echo "{$row['customer_ID']}, '{$row['Email']}'";?>)" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">
                    <span data-toggle="modal" data-target="#rejectModal">
                        
</span> No</a>
       
        </td>
        
        
        </tr>
```

the file below updates the table and a pop up shows allowing the user to send an email , it is here that i want the email that has been passed to display when the user clicks the link to get the windows pop up

```html
   
    <?php
    
include 'config.php';
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
   $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$query = "UPDATE booking SET status = 'REJECTED' WHERE customer_ID = '$id'";
$result = $conn->query($query);
if($result === TRUE){
 echo '';
?>
 
<?php
}
?>
  <form >
    <label type="text"  cass="fadeIn second" name="username" placeholder="User Name ">Booking has been rejected!</label>
    <label type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="password" placeholder="password">To email the customer for confirmation of rejection please click below!</label>
  <br>
                 <!--   <input href="emp_details_load.php"type = "submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value = " Submit "/><br /> -->
  <a href="<? php echo $email; ?>;subject=Booking request for O Driscolls Pub&body=Booking request for O Driscolls Pub">Send me an email</a>
</form>
```

does anyone have advise on how i would go about doing this

Comment: mailto, is sucks for  usability, how about sending the mail from the server

Comment: at the moment i havent it hosted online i am just using a local host @tim

Comment: @tim is there anyway of doing using mailto?4

Comment: You probably need to change `window.location.href ='Breject.php?id='+id+email;` to `window.location.href ='Breject.php?id='+id+'&email='+email;`, then just change `mailto:manish@simplygraphix.com` to `mailto:$Email`

Comment: @Nick when the email pops up in the sent to '$email' comes up instead of the actual email

Comment: @Nick i have updated my code to show what i have changed

Comment: `echo $row['customer_ID'], $row['Email'];` should be `echo "{$row['customer_ID']}, '{$row['Email']}'";` and `$email = $_POST['email'];` should be `$email = $_REQUEST['email'];`

Comment: @Nick i know get the error  Undefined index: email in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaperlessPub\Breject.php on line 6 when i press the reject button

Comment: `href="mailto:'$email'` should be `href="mailto:<? php echo $email; ?>`; the issue with the empty email in the URL should be resolved by the last change I suggested to the echo of the `$row` variables. Can you edit with your current code again please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189362/discussion-between-katie-o-donovan-and-nick).